# UI5: Does getRouter().getTargets().display() destroy the original/source view?

Tags: sapui5

At the [Step 5: Display a Target Without Changing the Hash](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/d9efab307ecc42b180b12cc8956e22d7), we can see a technique, which allows displaying a view without changing the hash, in other words, it displays a desired view without navigating to this view (if I understand it correctly).

That's nice, but does

```js
const oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(oView);

oRouter.getTargets().display("%DESIRED_VIEW%");

// alternatively:
// this.getRouter().getTargets().display("%DESIRED_VIEW%");
```

mean that the previous view, which rose `%DESIRED_VIEW%` will be properly destroyed in terms of garbage collector? In other words, is `*.getTargets().display()` technique is memory leak safe? What happens with the original (source) view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view in UI5 is never destroyed once it is displayed (and controller's `onInit` is also called only once).

If you take a look at the [sample app for step 5 of the routing tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/demokit/tutorial/navigation/05/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-theme=sap_fiori_3), you see a small app, that opens a second view when clicking a button.

In the [UI5 diagnostics](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/04b75eae78ef4bae9b40cd7540ae8bdc) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), you can see the control tree for both views:

[image: control tree for both views]

Also, when you deploy the UI5 application, the tooling will generate a `Component-preload.js` file that contains all views and JS files in one file.

So no, there is no garbage collector cleaning anything up for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've just remember in [Step 19: Reuse Dialogs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370) there is a mention of memory cleaning issue: _«Therefore we delete our reference to the `HelloDialog` instance by calling `delete this._helloDialog` and the garbage collection of the browser can clean up its memory.»_ I though, there is something similar here as well.

Comment: @MikeB. Btw. the "Step 19: Reuse Dialogs" was removed two days ago: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/commit/ba8c650034a1ec919562dab11c5a6eff632f9f01. Personally, I think `_helloDialog` was a questionable approach and quite unconventional.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, yes, I've paid attention and was quite surprised, hence: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/issues/59. But what would you recommend then to gain the similar behavior?